# Deleting objects in Qt Thread after thread finishes

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am newbee at QThreads and a problem that I am suspicious of deleting the objects when  the program finishes.My program has a class that derived from QObject:

```
class My_application: public QCoreApplication{
   ....
   ....
};

class My_Class: public QObject{
  ...
  ...
}; 

void My_Class::process{

     QTimer timer=new QTimer();
     timer->setInterval(time);
     connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(dowork()));
     timer->start(); 

} 

 My_application::My_application:QCoreApplication{

    my_class=new My_Class();

    QThread thread=new QThread();

    my_class->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),my_class,SLOT(process())) ;

    connect(my_class,SIGNAL(finished()),thread,SLOT(quit())) ;

    connect(thread,SIGNAL(finished()),thread,SLOT(deletelater())) ;

    connect(my_class,SIGNAL(finished()),my_class,SLOT(deletelater())) ;        


 }

   void My_Class::dowork(){

  //here doing the work with timer elapsed.Doing work with some buffer and send data 
  //               

  }
```

If I stop my program I see that some objects are not deleted correctly and my program does not work when I restart it.Actually I am not so familiar with Qt threads and i wonder when does the destructor of My_Class will be called? and am i doing the wrong thing?

Comment: Not sure but you can use deleteLater() with your thread connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater())); and be cautious with deleteLater() with this post as reference . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632989/qobjectdeletelater-across-a-qthread

Comment: Does you class contain 'finished' signal? Where do you emit it?

Comment: Well, at least [`QThread::finished()` signal](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#finished) connected to `deleteLater()` is the canonical way to delete objects when their thread finishes, so you're doing that right, I'd remove the other `deleteLater()` connection just to keep things tidy.

Comment: How do you stop your program? Also, why did you subclass QCoreApplication?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to control lifetime of your timer (in `My_Class::process`):

`connect( this, SIGNAL( destroyed() ), timer, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );`

or `QTimer timer=new QTimer( **this** );`

You should delete `my_class=new My_Class();` manually. It will not be deleted on `finished` signal of thread, because there will be no event loop to process `deleteLater` slot.

I'm confused, why you don't want to declare `my_class` as member of `My_application` ?

Comment: @dimitry you are right i was trying to run these in a loop so i forgot to call emitFinished.SO there is another question.If I call emit finished and clear the objects.And then continue to loop does it run second time correctly?I want to clear the objects and run everything again wşthout closing the program

Comment: So I want when I close my_program ,.ı want my application to send finisded to thread and thread to send finished to my_class and my_class to destroy objects

Comment: Your applicatioin will send `aboutToClose`. On this signal you should stop all threads, wait for real stop and destroy objects. It is not necessary to implement all logic with voodooing signals and slots.

Comment: Why don't you make `timer` a member of the `My_Class`. In the constructor, create the `QTimer` as a child object of `My_Class` (using `new QTimer(this)`). You can also move the `timer` initialisation code to the constructor and leave only `timer->start()` in `My_Class::process()`

Comment: @Dmitry: The official documentation (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html) says "From Qt 4.8 onwards, it is possible to deallocate objects that live in a thread that has just ended, by connecting the finished() signal to QObject::deleteLater()"